# Error/warning when using alert with text field

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, uitextfield, alert

I get the following warning/error when I create an alert with text field. When I remove the textfield, the message disappears.

> Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionViewCell that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing. View: <_UIAlertControllerTextFieldViewCollectionCell: 0x1529254e0; frame = (0 0; 270 24); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000d56be0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000003b5a80>>

I don't have a collection view and also I haven't changed or set to false the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a cell, that's why I don't understand the message.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(createAlert))
}
    
@objc private func createAlert() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {  _ in 
        print("Action") }

        alert.addAction(okAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        alert.addTextField { textField in
            
        }
        present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

How can I solve this? Unfortunately, I have not found a solution in my research. The warning occurs not only on the simulator, but also on physical devices (iPhone X).

Comment: Sounds like a bug with Apple, you should submit a feedback for them https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/